# How to Add authentication for self hosted web API?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, authorization, odata, odatacontroller

I have a self hosted Web API in console project. I need to authroize the 
user on role based or domain based.

How can i achieve it.

Sample Code :

-- Here how can i implement the Authentication and authorization --

```
public class Sample : ODataController
 {
[EnableQuery]
public IHttpActionResult Get(ODataQueryOptions<APINAME> opts)
                        {

                         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the both. In **AD** you set **user groups** and you assign **specific permission** to groups.

You need to keep in mind that users come and go but groups can stay definitely

I've worked on this kind of project 8 years ago.

- The frontend was writing everything in a database (MS-SQL)
- A windows service was querying a **Status** table which was reporting db activities
- That windows service was applying the ACL according to the **Status** refs

We were in Windows Server environment, I was using CMD (MS DOS **ICACLS**)

In .Net or from Powershell or from MS DOS you can apply ACLs

**Some resources**

[CACLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cacls) before ICACLS which seems more complex

[An illustrations in Windows where you can see the changes you made](https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Unknown-SID.png)

[This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11677763/3998265) may help you

Comment: What do you need me to explain, how to apply ACL ? How to manage users / groups ?

Comment: I've updated my answer, **note** you should think of a Web Service which will monitor queries and apply ACL